# How to find a particle's position after it off on the tangent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

Problem:

*A particle follows a trajectory given by $\sigma(t)=(t^{2},t^{3}-4t,0)$ and it off at a tangent at $t=2$. Find the particle's position at $t=3$. Make a draw of what is happening.*

Solution:

[image: Particle's position]

And this is what I did to find the position at $t=2$:

First, to find the particle new position it's required to find a point $P$ and direction vector $\vec{v}$:

$P$: $\sigma(2)=(4,0,0)$

$\vec{v}$: $\sigma'(2)=(4,8,0)$

Hence, the equation to find the new particle position is:

$l(t)=P+(t-2)\vec{v}$

Is that correct? Does the equation model the particle's position at any given $t$ time?

Comment: I think there's a missing word in your problem statement: "...and it [moves] off at a tangent at $t=2$."

Comment: That's how I would interpret your problem.  The particle departs from the curve along the tangent line with the imparted velocity from differentiating the parameterized curve.  It remains to locate the particle at $t=3$, according to the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct, expect for "Does the equation model the particle's position at any given $t$?" It is only valid for $t\geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have obtained is indeed the correct form of the tangent line. Another way to obtain this is to expand component to first order in $t-2$:

\begin{align}
\sigma(t)
&=(t^2,t^3-4t,0)\\
&=([(t-2)+2]^{2},t(t-2)(t+2),0)\\
&\approx (4+4(t-2),8(t-2),0)\\
&=(4,0,0)+(4,8,0)(t-2).
\end{align}
This is exactly the form you found.